# Converting normal sql query into hibernate criteria query

Tags: hibernate-criteria

i need to convert this sql query to hibernate criteria,please help guys.

SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS app
FROM device
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY app DESC
LIMIT 3

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select device.name, count(device)
from Device device
group by device.name
order by count(device) desc
```

This assumes that you have an entity class called `Device` with a field `name` along with a getter method `getName()`.  You may have to change the query depending on what your actual code is (which you never showed us).

The `LIMIT` clause you had is not applicable for HQL.  Instead, you should be doing `Query.setMaxResults()`.